# ModPagespeed domain dynamic url in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I'm currently using this snippet of code in my .htaccess for Pagespeed:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeedDomain cdn.example.com
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain cdn.example.com *example.com
</IfModule>
```

I'd like something like this (Doesn't work):

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeedDomain cdn.%{HTTP_HOST}
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain cdn.%{HTTP_HOST} *%{HTTP_HOST}
</IfModule>
```

I'm looking for a way to keep these variables dynamic so that I don't have to add this by hand per client. I'm also trying to avoid creating a PHP script to do this if there is a way to keep everything in .htaccess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed doesn't currently have a way to make this easier for you, sorry!  Interpreting `%{VARIABLE}`s would be a good feature to add.